# javascript extending functions

Tags: javascript

I read a book about how to extend object with a method:
I was confused with the following code:

> > Array.prototype._m=Array.prototype.m ||
> >     (  Array.prototype.m=function(){
> > //codes
> > })
> >     Object.prototype.m=Array.prototype._m

It's said that the code like this is safe and high compatibility.
But I can't see how it works 
And why

> > Array.prototype.m=function(){}

is not safe enough
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tylermwashburn explained it well.

Basically...

```
Array.prototype.m
Array.prototype._m
Object.prototype.m
```

...will all reference the same function. Either whatever was stored in `Array.prototype.m` or the new function if `Array.prototype.m` didn't exist.

I'd just add that it is really a bad idea to extend `Object.prototype`. It extends every object type in javascript.

I'd wonder about the book you're reading if that's what it suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What this is saying is if `!!Array.prototype.m` is true, then Array.prototype._m should equal Array.prototype.m.

If `!!Array.prototype.m` is false, the it sets `Array.prototype.m`, and then sets `Array.prototype._m` to it.

It then applies that method to `Object.prototype`.

Really this is just a long way of `Object.prototype.m = Array.prototype.m`.

The difference is that this makes sure it's defined first.

Comment: What is the `!!` in front of `Array.prototype.m` for? Not not?!

Comment: @w3c It turns whatever's infront of it into a boolean.